# PhoneGap ChildBrowser and Foursquare

Tags: cordova, foursquare, phonegap-plugins

i'm developping an application with phonegap. I want to integrate foursquare in my App.
How can i store and retrieve the access_token of foursquare to use it in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i take a quick look at the foursquare documentation than it looks quite easy to retrieve the token with javascript and the [oauth js](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/) library.
Just check out the [documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth) and [tutorial](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/tutorial).

To store your data inside your app you can do that easily by using [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

If you are using a server side solution to handle your api calls. You can save your token into a session and simply do a ajax request where you return the content of your session. (then use localStorage once again...)